# Django user.is_authenticated works some places, not others

Tags: django, django-users

In my template, I have the following:

```
        <ul class="tabbed" id="network-tabs">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url acct-my-profile %}">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url acct-logout %}">Log Out</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url acct-login %}">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url acct-register %}">Register</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

It seems to work fine, unless the page been created has a @login_required decorator, in which case the page works fine but the navigation appears as if the user is not logged in, even when they are.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should check your view function to see where the `user` variable is coming from. Unless you're specifically passing `user` into the context from the view, that's your problem.

You *do* have access to `request.user`, though, and that will always return true in a template rendered from a view that has the `@login_required` decorator.

The reason I can tell you for certain that there's nothing wrong with the decorator, though, is that in the code for `User` and `AnonymousUser` (located in `django.contrib.auth.models`) the `is_authenticated` method strictly returns true for `User` and false for `AnonymousUser`. The decorator does not and cannot change that. And what that means is that your template isn't actually getting a `User` object where you're checking `user`.

Comment: Ah! Perfect. I wasn't passing the user through at all, just as you said. But for others (since it confused me), you can't use "request.user" in the template, you need to pass through the user in your render to response like: 'user' : request.user,

Thanks again.

Comment: See Alasdair's answer for further information in response to your comment.

Answer (score 8):

To follow on from Gabriel's answer, is the `user` variable coming from the auth context processor? If it is, and you are using the `render_to_response` shortcut, you need to use a `RequestContext` instance.

```
from django.template import RequestContext

...

@login_required
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Also an excellent point. I was about to add a note on context processors and RequestContext.

Comment: I am having this problem too: after login correctly, I redirect to home page, wich view returns render_to_response('myapp/shop_list.html', 
       {'shop': entry_list,},
       context_instance=RequestContext(request)) But, at this point, request.user is an AnonymusUser so when the home page template loads, user.is_authenticated is always false. What can I be missing?

Comment: It sounds like your login isn't working. If you add `print request.user` to your home page view, do you get the user you are expecting? If that doesn't help, please ask a new question instead of adding comments here -- not many people will read these comments, so you won't get any help.