# django-registration, User missing after login

Tags: django, authentication, request, django-registration, requestcontext

First at all, I have to say that I've followed a few SO answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337419/django-user-is-authenticated-works-some-places-not-others) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753413/authenticated-but-user-is-authenticated-remains-false)) but I havent solved my problem.

Well, I am using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` (that works correctly) via django-registration and I have set the `next="/home_page/"` param in the login form. The view asociated to `/home_page/` is excuted, its return looks like this:

```
return render_to_response('myapp/shop_list.html', 
                        {'shop': entry_list,},
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I didnt render any other template between login and this view but, while debugging, I've realized that the **`User` is not in the request** before this return so the template recieves an `AnonymousUser` and `user.is_authenticated()` returns False

The user is in the DDBB and the password is correct. How can I get the logged User at this point?

Here is some information about my app that may be helpful:

```
settings.py
===========

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'myapp',
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

login.html
==========

{% block maincontent %}
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/home_page/" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
{% endblock %}

link to login
=============

<a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: After you call login() do you receive a valid instance of the User?

Comment: Debugging django.contrib.auth.views.login I see how the User instance is created after login correctly, but it is missing in the home_page view.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you're doing. Maybe paste your whole views.py and that might provide a clue. Also try putting @login_required on your /home_page view (although this shouldn't be required as you are redirecting here after login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I created an authentication backend, for another purpose, and the authenticate method wasn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Really, the only thing that could cause something like that is not having cookies enabled in your browser, or cookies otherwise not being stored.

When you login, a session is created, the logged in user is added to the session and a session cookie is delivered to the client (your browser). On the next request, your browser will send the cookie back to the server, which uses it to pull the matching session out of the database and populate `request.user` with the user that was logged in (simplified explanation here, of course).

So, really the only way for `request.user` to be an `AnonymousUser` is to have either not logged in or not sent the cookie to the server.

Check the settings in your browser as well as any extensions you may be running to make sure nothing is interfering with cookies. You might want to try another browser, and see if the behavior is repeatable.

Comment: +1: It most probably is the problem I'm guessing. Might be worth trying a different browser too.

Comment: Yes, what I understood about this proccess is that when you render a template, you have to add the User to the request applying TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS by using the third argument of the render function (context_instance=RequestContext(request)). Maybe the home_page view doesnt recieved the user cause no template has been rendered between the login and the view, but I though django.contrib.auth did that for you

Comment: ah! cookies are enabled in firefox and chrome

Comment: The auth context processor adds `user` and `perms` to your template context. `RequestContext` makes `request` available in your template context. The template being rendered has nothing to do with anything. Have you followed any of the advice in my answer yet?

Comment: While debuging django.contrib.auth.views.login I can see that when it authenticates correctly it returns return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to) so it doesnt render any template, maybe thats why I cannot find the user in the next view. Any help?

Comment: Of course it doesn't render a view. The login view always just redirects to another view when it's done, but the next view *does* render a template. Regardless, though, the act of rendering a template has no bearing one way or another on what's stored in `request.user`. If your next view also didn't render a template, and just redirected again, it would still have access to `request.user`.