# Django user.is_authenticated returns different results in different views

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an API view (using DJ Rest Framework) that I am posting to via React in my frontend.  `request.user.is_authenticated` returns True here (and returns the user I have attempted to sign-in as), however, in my view for rendering the login page template, `request.user.is_authenticated` returns False, and the user object is an `AnonymousUser`.

Why is this?

I've checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337419/django-user-is-authenticated-works-some-places-not-others), but it only has information on templates.

Here's the API view code:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_api_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
        return Response({'message': 'User is already authenticated'}, status=400)

    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'message': 'Please specify a username and password'}, status=400)

    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is None:
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=401)
    login(request, user)

    return Response({'message': 'Successfully authenticated user'}, status=200)
```

And here's the code for the template:

```py
def login_view(request, *args, **kwars):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    
    return render(request, 'users/login.html')
```

Comment: I don't get it, is `login_view` being called by the `login_api_view` function?

Comment: No, `login_view` is what is rendering the login form page.  In my React code, I'm POSTing an XHR to `login_api_view` with the provided credentials.

Comment: Just to make sure, is the decorator for the `login_view` GET request missing or is it just omitted from your question?

Comment: You don't need decorator's for regular, non-rest-framework, Django views, right? Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie.  If you do, I have no clue how any of my code is working.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right. I could be misremembering things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stopping work on this for a few days and coming back to it, I've found that my Dev Authentication class (`rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication`) was messing with my results.